# Azure Hybrid Connection trouble-shooting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In both Azure and the Hybrid Connection Manager I have a status of 'Connected' but when I try tcpping to it fails.

Apart from tccping, is there any other trouble shooting I can do?

The HCM endpoint is DESDESKTOP-6E0E4QK:5162.  Here are my tccping results

> tcpping DESDESKTOP-6E0E4QK:5162
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot
>   Connection attempt failed: No such host is known
>   Connection attempt failed: No such host is known
>   Connection attempt failed: No such host is known
>   Connection attempt failed: No such host is known
>   Complete: 0/4 successfull attempts (0%). Average success time: 0ms

Internal IP that resolves to DESDESKTOP-6E0E4QK

> tcpping 192.168.1.158:5162
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot
>   Connection attempt failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.1.158:5162
>   Connection attempt failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.1.158:5162
>   Connection attempt failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.1.158:5162
>   Connection attempt failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 192.168.1.158:5162
>   Complete: 0/4 successfull attempts (0%). Average success time: 0ms

External IP

> tcpping 47.198.9.249:5162
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot
>   Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
>   Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
>   Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
>   Connection attempt failed: Connection timed out.
>   Complete: 0/4 successfull attempts (0%). Average success time: 0ms

Comment: `tcpping` won't work, it will lie to you since it's testing web app to HC endpoint (in Azure) not web app to on-prem. Use a real client, like curl or sqlcmd or whatever's needed for the daemon listening on port 5162 on prem.

Comment: Chances are the reason is because you have configured your Hybrid Connection so that it actually gets by-passed when you attempt to connect to your on-premise resource. I suggest you take a look into this blog:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/05/22/hybrid-connection-shows-connected-but-application-fails-to-connect/

Comment: Thanks evilSnobu.  I'll try out curl.  Do you have any other trouble-shooting tips?

Comment: Thanks Ajay.  I read the blog earlier.  When I did a 'hostname' from the command prompt, it returned DESDESKTOP-6E0E4QK so I think it is configured correctly.

Comment: @RichardButterwood The port 5162 is running on Azure VM? Could you tcping this port on your local?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT The port is running on an on-prem server.  When I did